# How to create a method to call from object.attribute in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm saving phone numbers as domestic on a `phone` field on a `User` model.

I did a quick method to convert the number to international.

My question is how to make this method available like this

```
@user.phone.to_international
```

Rather than my current

```
to_international(@user.phone.to_international,@user.phone.country)
```

Any idea how to do accomplish this?

Comment: Add it to whatever class the phone number is?

Comment: The class is `User`. How can I do to respond to attribute `phone` and not to model `User`?

Comment: No, the user is class user. The phone is class something else.

Comment: Then how can I edit the phone class? I through the attr_accessibles here were a method from `ActiveRecord::Base` class.

Comment: attr_accessible has nothing to do with it--if it's a database primitive, it's a string, int, date, etc. I don't know what it is, can't see it from here. You add class methods the same way as always in Ruby--classes are open!

Comment: see my answer below, surely the phone attribute is a String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, but not sure if after_initialize is better or not

Add this to your User model

```
after_find :prepare_phone

private
def prepare_phone
  def phone.to_international
    self.upcase # change with whatever you want. 'self' is the phone attr 
  end
end
```

Comment: This might be better if you only ever need it in the international format. If you needed access to the original value, not so much.

Comment: Actually this doesn't solve your problem. We have to know what user is

Comment: Why? Assuming user is an AR model, which seems reasonable, why wouldn't this work?

Comment: Well, never mind, I was thinking to much. I'm glad it worked.

Comment: This is a bad idea and you don't want to get in the habit of doing this.  Both the after_find and after_initialize callbacks are executed whenever a user object is instantiated.  Do you really want to add the overhead of setting up this method every time a user object is instantiated, in the long run the answer should be no.

Comment: @PatrickKlingemann, I actually agree with you. There are better ways, like the one you tell in your answer.

Comment: @ismaelgo: I did appreciate your answer, it prompted a few minutes of toying in irb.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class called phone with a to_international method, and set the phone property in the user class to be an instance of the phone class.

Answer (score -1):

Monkey patch the `String` class.  In `myapp/config/initializers/string_monkey_patches.rb` add:

```
String.class_eval do
  PHONE_NUMBER_FORMAT = // # some regex matching a phone number
  def to_international
    raise 'Invalid phone number format' unless self.match(PHONE_NUMBER_FORMAT)
    # convert self (the phone number string) to an international number
  end
end
```